# How to print list of string inside bracket?

Tags: java, string, printing, java.util.scanner, brackets

I am new to Java. I am facing a problem to print a list of string separated by commas inside brackets.

```
public class House extends Property { 
protected static List<String> paints;
public String paint;

public House() {
    super("House", 45);
    String paints = new String();
    System.out.print(paints);
}

public void addPaint(String paint) {
    this.paint = paint;
    ArrayList<String> House = new ArrayList<String>();
    House.add(" ");

public void display() {
    super.display();
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(paint);
    StringJoiner strJoin = new StringJoiner(", ", " { ", " }");
    words.forEach((s)->strJoin.add(s));
    if (paint == null || "".equals(paint)) {
        System.out.print(" { }");
    }

    else {
    System.out.print(strJoin);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        House house1 = new House();
        house1.addPaint("Red");
        house1.addPaint("Blue");
        house1.addPaint("Yellow");
        house1.display();
    }
```

It should be printed like this for a house with colors:

```
45 House { Red, Blue, Yellow }
```

Or like this for a house without color (empty):

```
45 House { }
```

However, the output of my code only prints the last added color:

```
45 House { Yellow }
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: What is _topping_ here? Show us minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edit your question to include `House`. We can speculate about what you've done wrong in `addPaint` - but without seeing it, we can't possibly say for sure.

Comment: I have edited the information on my post. Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
public class House {
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public void addPaint(String color)
    {
        colors.add(color);        
    }
    public void display()
    {   String value = "";
        for (String color : colors)
        value += color + ", ";
        value = value.substring(0, value.length()-2);
        System.out.println("{ " + value + " }");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    House house1 = new House();
    house1.addPaint("Red");
    house1.addPaint("Blue");
    house1.addPaint("Yellow");
    house1.display();
}

// Output: { Red, Blue, Yellow }
```

Answer (score 1):

To group a list of strings using a prefix and suffix you can use `Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix,CharSequence suffix))`, example :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> colors = List.of("Red", "Blue", "Yellow");
        String result = colors.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" , ", "{", "}"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

this will print `{Red , Blue , Yellow}` and if list is empty it will print `{}`

**Note that**:

- I think you should review your model design ^^ !
- I've used `List.of()` in my example to demonstrate the "how to", knowing that it requires java 9 or above

Comment: Thank you so much @Abdelghani Roussi. How if the list of the string depends on user input? Maybe there are less than 3 or more than 3 strings.

Comment: @Elizabeth it doesn't matter if there is 0 or n element (the list is transformed to a stream) however it shouldn't be null ;) so a null check is required to avoid NPE

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `paint` as a String (and not a List of Strings) here.

```
public String paint;
```

And then you convert the String variable to a List.

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(paint);
```

Which is why the list `words` has only the single String which was added last with `house1.addPaint()`, which just assigns the String `this.paint = paint;` inside it.

There are many ways you can fix it. But I'll tell the one that requires the least amount of changes.

**My suggestion:**

```
public void addPaint(String paint) {
    paints.add(paint);
}
```

and

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(paints);
```